# Prevent adding class to li childs

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

In this case:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">menu item</a></li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
var myMenu = $('.menu li');

myMenu.mouseenter(function () {
    myMenu.filter('.active').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
</script>
```

jquery add class to every `li` on hover, but i **don't** want to add class into the `li` childs.

i mean `.menu li ul li`

how can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `var myMenu = $('.menu > li');` ?

Comment: @newbie If this actually answered your question, think about putting it solved, in order to close the topic ;)

Comment: @newbie you have to accept the answer if it helps,just to boost us and to help you more :) .

Comment: @newbie No problem at all ;)